# Is there a better way to redirect and pass parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table

```
<table id="tableDg" border=1>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td ><input type="hidden" id="path" readonly="true" value="{path}">{path}</input></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class = "chkbCsm" ></input></td>
  <td ><input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{name}"><a href="#"  class="aDg">{name}</a></input></td> 
     <td ><input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{host}">{host}</input>     </td> 
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

After reading post from **Felix Kling**
My jQuery

```
$('#tableDg tbody tr td a.aDg').live('click', function(){
    path=$('input', $(this).parent().prev().prev()).val();
    window.location.href = "/simon/infopage.html";

     var url_action="/getData";
     var client; 
     var dataString;

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
         client=new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {                    
         client=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     client.onreadystatechange=function(){

         if(client.readyState==4&&client.status==200)
         {
                   //here i will get back path in infopage.html
         }
     };

     dataString="request=getconfigdetails&path="+path;
     client.open("POST",url_action,true);
     client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

     client.send(dataString);

});
```

Is this how i should get `path` from my previous page to `infopage.html`

Comment: And you don't want to have `path` shown in the address bar?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, after the page is redirected, the `path` remains visible in my address bar, which i don't want

Comment: Where do you need the `path` value? Server side or client side? Why don't you do a POST request?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I need `path` in `infopage.html` page so that using the path in `infopage.html` i can call my server to fetch an xml and populate areas in my `infopage.html` page

Comment: @Felix Kling: I updated my question to send request to server side, I want to know whether this way can i get `path` to infopage.html? Or guide me to a proper way. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `$.ajax`? There is no good reason for not using it since you already use jQuery...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I am just familiar with this approach

Comment: I used ajax call. thanks @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 0):

You could have the first page set a cookie, then redirect and read it on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like that:

```
$('#tableDg tbody tr td a.aDg').live('click', function(){
    $('#tableDg').append('<form action="/simon/infopage.html" id="myform" method="post"> place some inputs here </form>');
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Comment: Not that acrion should be action in the <form>.